Does Mintupdate have a open source license
I have forked mintupdate (mintupdate repository), but when I looked I could not find a license.
Is this code open source and if so, where can I find the license? I plan to use some of its code to develop a non-interactive version that can be used with distributed management applications, such as SALT. I would like to include a license that is the same as that for the source.

Yes, it’s licensed under the GPL, version 3 or later.

Thanks. I am not experienced in modifying licenses to incorporate code from another repo. I have made an attempt to do this and I wonder if you might take a look at the result to see if I have correctly executed it. The only routine I have used from mintupdate is usr/lib/linuxmint/mintUpdate/rel_upgrade_root.py, which I have renamed python/mintupdate-ni.py. All other files are created from scratch. The copyright file is here: https://github.com/dnessett/mintupdate-ni.git. I have attempted to credit the author of rel_upgrade_root.py correctly.

I should have mentioned that I have modified usr/lib/linuxmint/mintUpdate/rel_upgrade_root.py (there doesn't seem to be a way to edit comments).

I just moved python/mintupdate-ni.py to /salt/scripts/mintupdate-ni.py

@dnessett Possibly picky, but the GPL3+ license notification is only in the ./debian directory. No top-level license is granted, so it's possible that files under ./usr are protected by copyright and no distribution has been granted. Definitely an oversight on the package authors.

@doneal24 I agree the license documentation isn’t perfect (in fact, it doesn’t follow the GPL guidelines), but in Debian source packages, debian/copyright documents the license of all the files in the source, not just debian. Given that that file was committed by Clement Lefebvre, who wrote most of the rest of the code, I reckon it’s valid.
